# ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (Unknown MySQL error)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I try to run gem 'thinking-sphinx' on my Ruby on Rails project, but something was wrong. When I run any *search* command on any model, I see this error: ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (Unknown MySQL error).

More details:

- MacOS Mojave -v 10.14.3
- mysql -v 8.0.15 (Installed first)
- Sphinx -v 2.2.11_2 (Installed via 'brew install sphinx')
- thinking-sphinx -v 4.2.0
- Rails -v 5.2.2

Before run *search* command, I runned *rails ts:index* and *rails ts:start*
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx v2.2 (and 3.0) is not compatible with MySQL v8. You'll either want to downgrade MySQL to 5.7 - which can be done with homebrew via `brew install mysql@5.7` - and then uninstall and reinstall Sphinx, or [download the binaries for Sphinx v3.1.1](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/current/) (the first version to support MySQL v8) from the Sphinx website (the source code for that release is not currently available, hence it's not installable via homebrew).

Comment: I installed mysql@5.7, following the instructions in the link https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21. Before installation I removed mysql -v8. But I see the same error. Maybe this is due to the fact that when installing the sphinx in the console is displayed `Installing sphinx dependency: mysql; Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-8.0.15.mojave.bottle.tar.gz`

Comment: Now `mysql -V` returns `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: Is there a way to tell Homebrew not to install the latest (v8) MySQL as a dependency of Sphinx? Otherwise, you may want to get the 2.2.11 binaries from the Sphinx website (or the source and compile it yourself).

Comment: @Mr.DannyX how you fix this issue?

Comment: @pat how to compile after downloading?

Answer (score 1):

Just changed mysql2 from `gem "mysql2", '~> 0.4.6'`  to `gem "mysql2", '0.4.10'` version, and it worked for me. Thanks