# ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (Unknown MySQL error):

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

ThinkingSphinx was working fine in my app on Ubuntu and MacOS Mojave. Then I upgrade my macOS to Catalina 10.15.4 . Now thinking sphinx giving error Unknown MySQL.

Altough commands like `rake ts:rebuild` , `rake ts:index` are working fine but when I search on model  it gives an error `ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: Unknown MySQL error`.

Mysql Version is 8. As per [Unknown Mysql Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187763/thinkingsphinxsphinxerror-unknown-mysql-error) Sphinx v2.2 (and 3.0) is not compatible with MySQL v8. So I download sphinx 3.2.1 and place its bin folder inside /usr/local/bin but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm: you will need to place the binaries from the downloaded `bin` folder inside `/usr/local/bin` - but not the downloaded `bin` folder itself.

So, make sure that `/usr/local/bin/searchd` is the right version - just use the full path, no arguments. And confirm that you've not put the files at `/user/local/bin/bin/searchd`, etc.